# Blend 4 trigger rendering not working

Tags: wpf, xaml, expression-blend

Ive got a really frustrating bug going on with Blend 4, when i edit a control template with triggers, if i switch to one of the triggers, the trigger changes are not shown in the design pane, its like ive turned off trigger rendering somehow

Reproduction Steps

Create a new WPF application in visual studio 2010
Open new solution in blend
Drag a "SimpleButton" onto the design surface
Right click on the button>Edit Style>Edit Current
On the triggers tab, select any of the triggers and nothing changes in the design view

This behaviour only appears if
The style is defined in a resource dictionary
The template is contained within a style, ie , not

Does anyone know any workarounds or fixes for this, i get it on both my home and work machines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a reply on the expression forums, they have confirmed it as a bug, here's the reply

> Thanks for bringing this to our
> attention, we've confirmed this
> regression from V3 behavior and we've
> filed a bug. If you select a trigger,
> even though it doesn't appear to be
> selected (the artboard doesn't
> immediately update), changes are
> recorded at leaves. And we have
> noticed behavior that you might want
> to use as a workaround. If you perform
> the following steps then the trigger
> is applied to the artboard:
>
> 1. Select a trigger
> 2. Click the style segment on the breadcrumb
> 3. Click the template segment on the breadcrumb
> 4. re-select the trigger

My post on the expression forums:

http://social.expression.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/blend/thread/0f6a1422-86e5-4a2e-ad72-1f273f8671dc?prof=required

Answer (score 0):

I got exact same problem and I think it is because if the files were modified in Visual Studio and if the project was not build within the expression I used to get the same problem. What I did was, close Visual Studio, open Project in Expression Blend and build the project before editing template.

Also the problem could be source code control or team system, I did notice that if files werent checked out, blend didnt work correctly, I checked out entire project in Visual Studio then I was able to do everything in Blend.

Hope any of these two should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the tips but unfortunatly none helped
I tried creating a project from within blend its self, didnt use VS at all, built the project but still got the same issue
Also, these projects arent under source control